# Why is the performance of non-superscalar parts of a superscalar processor affected?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, processor

In the second-last paragraph of the [ILP section of Wikipedia's CPU article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit#Instruction-level_parallelism):

> In the case where a portion of the CPU is superscalar and part is not, **the part which is not suffers a performance penalty due to scheduling stalls**. The Intel P5 Pentium had two superscalar ALUs which could accept one instruction per clock cycle each, but its FPU could not accept one instruction per clock cycle. Thus the P5 was integer superscalar but not floating point superscalar.

**What is a scheduling stall?**  Why does the performance of the non-superscalar part of the CPU suffer from it?

Is this saying that the scalar part is slower than it would be if the rest of the CPU was scalar?

Comment: Can you quote more of the exact wording?  Are they counting it as a stall when a sequence of FP instructions only runs at 1 IPC instead of the optimal 2 IPC for instructions that can pair?

Comment: "In the case where a portion of the CPU is superscalar and part is not, the part which is not suffers a performance penalty due to scheduling stalls. The Intel P5 Pentium had two superscalar ALUs which could accept one instruction per clock cycle each, but its FPU could not accept one instruction per clock cycle. Thus the P5 was integer superscalar but not floating point superscalar. Intel's successor to the P5 architecture, P6, added superscalar capabilities to its floating point features, and therefore afforded a significant increase in floating point instruction performance."

Comment: Sorry that I didn't correctly remember where the words are from. It is actually from Wikipedia.

Comment: I rewrote your question to more clearly ask what I think you're trying to ask.  And to link to the source of the quote, like you should have done with an edit once you remembered where it was from.

Comment: Is P5 able to perform one ALU operation and one FPU operation at same time ? (technically it should but maybe controller unit is not able to do that). I am asking this because I read somewhere that Quake was much slower on Cyrix because "it use cleverly optimized x86 code that interleaved FPU and integer instructions" and "those operations used different parts of the Pentium core and could effectively be overlapped".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hadn't heard the term "scheduling stall" before, but it sounds like it's just saying that the pipeline will bottleneck on the scalar part.

The scalar part still runs at its max throughput.  So I think the wording of that wikipedia article is misleading:  "the part which is not suffers a performance penalty" certainly makes it sound like the scalar part will *not* achieve its own max throughput.

I guess this counts as a "stall" if the superscalar part of the CPU is expecting to issue 2 instructions per cycle but it's only able to issue 1 because there aren't execution resources available.

Answer (score 1):

A superscalar processor/core is the one which can decode more than one instructions in parallel and a processor/core is seen superscalar in totality not in it's parts. Not sure if there is some standard definition of "scheduling stalls" but author's purpose is to highlight the stalls in the pipeline caused by the constrained of execution units (limited to having only two ALUs and one FPU) and it would have been better if he had used temm pipeline stalls. A stall happens when the i/p operands of an execution unit is not available or operands are available but execution unit is not available. For example in following code

```
int i1=1, i2=2, i3=3, i4=4;
float f1=1.0, f2=2.0;

i1 = i1 + i2;
i3 = i3 + i4;
f1 = f1 / (float) i1;
f2 = f2 / (float) i2;
```

first two instructions can be executed in parallel but as there is only one floating point unit hence last two instruction can't be executed in parallel. Hence the fourth instruction has to wait for scheduling as the floating point unit is occupied.

Comment: If this is what scheduling stall means, there are no differences whether other parts are superscalar or not?

Comment: floating point division is a terrible example.  No x86 CPUs have multiple dividers, because they're so expensive to implement in hardware.  A better example would be `f1 = f1 + f1` or something.  Intel Skylake can run two FP adds in parallel.

Comment: @Peter, I agree with you that floating point division takes too much cycles but does it implemented in h/w or through instructions available in the core

Comment: Yeah, all modern x86 CPUs support x87 `fidiv` (which is maybe what you're picturing for dividing a float by an int?), and `divss`.  That's not the point.  The point is that no CPUs can execute them both *in parallel*, so the fourth instruction always has to wait.  A better example would be `f1 += f2`  and `f2 *= f2`, since `addss` and `mulss` can execute in parallel on Intel microarchitectures, including Pentium II.  See [Agner Fog's microarch guide and instruction tables](http://agner.org/optimize/), and other links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Comment: That would better illustrate the difference between P5 and P6.

Comment: My point was to highlight what could lead stalls for a given architecture of execution unit (in this case execution limited to 2 ALUs and 1 FPU). I was not considering the cost of unit. So any two floating point operations whether addition/subtractions/multiplication/division will lead to stall

Answer (score 1):

From wikipedia:

**Structural hazards**

A structural hazard occurs when **a part of the processor's hardware is needed by two or more instructions at the same time**. A canonical example is a single memory unit that is accessed both in the fetch stage where an instruction is retrieved from memory, and the memory stage where data is written and/or read from memory.[3] They can often be resolved by separating the component into orthogonal units (such as separate caches) or **bubbling the pipeline**.

---

P5 is a pipelined in-order superscalar(dual issued) microprocessor. So it can start 1 integer and 1 any operations at same cycle but can't re-order them and instruction issue is paired, not independent.

Important cases are:

- cpu doesn't know if instruction is a fp or int until decode stage(unless prefetched) so when only single pipeline is available, 2x fetch+decode capability is not useful
- even if multiple fp_add can be executed at the same time, they can't start at the same time --> performance hit
- if an instruction is not pairable, one pipeline stalls, moves stages to other pipeline, two instructions are serialized
- if both instructions(dual issued) are fp and one is not pairable, at least they are pipelined but limited to only a few instructions at the same time (number of stages are 8 for fp(higher = badder when stall) so not as efficient as integer)
- some iterative fp functions take all resources of fpu so no other fp instructions can be pipelined (FDIV stalls any new fp instructions ). May be 0.1-0.5 IPC. They re-use the registers and can't be used with mmx instructions at the same time.

Maximum of 3x fp_add can be executed at the same time (but not start same time as integers do) or 1 fp_mul + 2 fp_add can be executed at the same time(but can't start same time) and fpu consists of 8 stages so more than 3 additions start stalling until first one completes.

Maybe instead of

```
int = int + int              // start at cycle-0
int = int + int              // start at cycle-0
float = float + float        // start at cycle-1
float = float + float        // start at cycle-2
```

you could try

```
float = float + float     // start at cycle-0
int = int + int           // start at cycle-0
float = float + float     // start at cycle-1
int = int + int           // start at cycle-1
```

to get pairing working and have better performance.

Pure integer:

```
 i0 fetch
 i0 decode i1 fetch
 i0 operands from mem  i1 decode i2 fetch 
 i0 execute i1 operands i2 decode ... i3 something
 i0 store i1 execute i2 operands ...  i4 something
```

4 per pipeline running at the same time = 8 instructions unobstructed running= 2IPC

pure floating-point:

```
 f0-fetch
 f0-decode f1-fetch
 f0-operand f1-decode f2-fetch
 f0-execute f1-operand f2-decode (3rd fp issued, no more fp additions)
 f0-store ....
 fx-fetch
```

3 running in parallel, less than 1 IPC. FDiv is even slower.

Comment: To describe the situation where an FP add is still executing when another one starts, you can say that multiple FP adds are **in flight** at the same time, even though they can only be started at one per cycle.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes I meant in flight but I forgot the word. Thank you.